# I can't update Firefox for ubuntu

Tags: updates, firefox, browser

What is Latest version of Firefox for Ubuntu 17.10? I keep getting a warning saying Firefox version 56 is severely outdated.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading it? If yes, what are the error messages you got? It must be v60.

Comment: It's at version 60 now: https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/firefox

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of Firefox for Ubuntu is version 60.0.2.

Try

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```